# Get string between / in URL

Tags: javascript, html, string

Let's say I have the following URL `https://www.google.com/en-gb/test-page`.

I'm trying to extract whatever is after the domain name, in this case `en-gb`, however, with my approach, it's currently spitting out the entire slug.

I.e.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname.substr(1);
console.log(pathname);
```

**Will log out:**

`en-gb/test-page`

How can I get it so that it only log out `en-gb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the url with the `/` delimiter

```js
const url = 'https://www.google.com/en-gb/test-page';

console.log(url.split('/')[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URL.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname)

Code:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.google.com/en-gb/test-page');
const str = url.pathname.split('/')[1];

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on a slash:

```
var [pathname] = window.location.pathname.substr(1).split("/");
```